# override fadeout() display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BP6rq/1514/

Fades my element out and puts it in a `fixed` position once it has reached the necessary point. I am using `fadeOut()` for the back-in effect. The problem is I do not want it to hide. I know about `fadeTo`, however I haven't been able to achieve that same effect. I've also tried overriding the display: none, but that eliminates the functionality of the fade effect. What can I do to maintain the fade effect, but not have `fadeOut()` disappear when scrolled back up and back to its original position?

Thoughts?

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to achieve... your fiddle contradicts half of the things you wrote in your question

Answer (score 1):

Use `animate()` together with css `opacity` instead of fadeIn fadeOut:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BP6rq/1515/)</kbd>

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function () {
    $.fx.speeds.xslow = 250;
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('#bottomcta')
        .animate({
            'opacity': 1
        },1000)
        .addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#bottomcta')
        .animate({
            'opacity': 0
        },1000)
        .removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: cause display triggers sharp a state to another when opacity can be gradually  applied ... opacity gets a numeric value, display does not

Comment: With `opacity`, the element becomes invisible but is not removed from the DOM/flow

Comment: yes, you need then to remove it only once opacty is down to 0 or set it in absolute position to remove it from the flow of doc :) . My comment was actually an hint / extra info to explain your choice